# 'ElementAt' statement not supported in vb9.0

Tags: vb.net

I am working in an old project implemented with vb 9.0, and I have to add some class. When I use `ElementAt`, I have this error:

> 'ElementAt' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of ClassName)'.

What do I have to do?

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Public NotInheritable Class AnalysisEngine

    Public Shared Function ATR(ByVal input As List(Of ATRInput), ByVal Periods As Integer) As ATRResult
        Dim trueRangeList As New List(Of Double)
        For i As Integer = 0 To (input.Count - 1) Step 1
            Dim currentHigh As Double = input.ElementAt(i).High
        ' ....
    End Function
End Class
```

This is my code. The statement `input.ElementAt(i).High` is not supported.

Comment: You have to not use features from later versions of .NET, or else upgrade your old project to a current version of .NET.

Comment: Why don't you use the regular indexer? `Dim currentHight As Double = input(i).High`. If you don't need the index, you can also use a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the Linq extension here. Since .NET 2, `System.Collections.Generic.List(Of ClassName)` already has support for [accessing by index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc.aspx), just use:

```
yourList(3)
```

to get the "element at" position 3.